# QGIS 3.0 fails to read some font styles

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, font

There is a very strange problem with my QGIS 3.0 to show some font styles.

For example you can see that font **Gill Sans Ultra Bold** has 4 styles and QGIS 2.18.19 can see them:
[image]

But QGIS 3.0.3 fails to do that: 
[image]

I've tried to reinstall fonts, reinstall QGIS 3.0.3 but the issue isn't fixed.

(Update) It fails to read even **Ms Shell Dlg 2**:
[image]

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Does that font actually have those styles available? Check in word or some other app.

Comment: I have that same font installed on my Windows 10 system. It contains only 1 style: Regular. I checked it in Photoshop and Nexusfont.  Could it be the styles in QGIS 2.18 are generated by QGIS?

There is more software (like Word for example) that can show a font in italic or bold, even if the font file doesn't contain those styles.

Comment: @MichelStuyts and ndawson you are right. Those fonts don't have styles and perhaps QGIS 2.18 was generating them.

Comment: what happens if you use "Gill Sans Ultra" - which I guess will come with at least bold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking this font (Gill Sans Ultra Bold) in Photoshop and Nexusfont, Michel Styts found that it only contains one style, regular.

QGIS 2.18 must have been generating the other three styles. Some software (like Microsoft Word) can show a font in italic or bold, even if the font file doesn't contain those styles.

QGIS 3 uses the built-in styles only and does not generate any additional styles. So the font styles available in QGIS 3 will differ from the styles available in QGIS 2.18.

-paraphrased from comments by [ndawson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/28443/ndawson), [Michel Stuyts](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/43589/michel-stuyts) and [Vitruvius](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/99113/vitruvius).